# Why is my png not displaying on my WebPages site?

Tags: asp.net, html, href, webmatrix, asp.net-webpages

I've started my asp.net WebPages site using the "Starter Site" template. It contains a layout page, _SiteLayout.cshtml, that is referenced in Default.cshtml.

In _SiteLayout, there is this HTML:

```
    <header>
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <div class="float-left">
                <p class="site-title"><a href="~/Images/something.png"></a></p>
            </div>
```

It originally had one of the images that "came with" the site instead of "something.png" but since I did not see the original image in the browser when I ran it, I changed it first to ~/Images/orderedList7.png and then to "something.png" in an attempt to raise an err msg or warning. But no! Tolerance, your name is html! (or is it vice-versa?).

At any rate, why am I not seeing the image specified in the layout file when I run the site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<header>
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <div class="float-left">
                <p class="site-title"><img src="~/Images/something.png" /></p>
            </div>
```

Try that, you are using an anchor instead of an image tag.

Comment: Odd, because that's the code that comes "in the box" - I simply poked around it by changing the name of the .png

Comment: well, the code you have will only link to the image, not display it.

Comment: Oh, I see, so it's not a mistake on their part, but a hole in my understanding of what was supposed to be happening with it.

Comment: Sounds right, does the image work as expected with the img tag?